# Is it possible to add description of an app when creating by Platypus?

Tags: macos, install, java

I am creating an app by Platypus. Is there any way to **add description of an app** that would be visible in About menu? Or how it might be done?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It seems I have found the solution:
"If you add a file named Credits.rtf or Credits.html to the bundled files list, it will be displayed in the About window of your application.":
http://www.sveinbjorn.org/files/manpages/PlatypusDocumentation.html#817

Comment: Please provide  the answer rather than just a link